# Restricted Boltzmann Machine for grayscale images

Tags: neural-networks, image-processing, computer-vision, restricted-boltzmann-machine

I know that RBM's have been used on image data for pre-training neural nets, but all I can find are RBM's on black and white images. How do you apply them to say 256 grayscale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use Gaussian visible units instead of binary visible units. This is described in the practical guide for training RBM by G. Hinton.